# Apache server not accessible over Internet:

Tags: networking, debian, port-forwarding, apache-http-server

I am trying to access my web server (Debian, running Apache 2.2.22) from outside my LAN but the web browser says "This webpage is not available" when I type a.b.c.d:8080 in my URL bar (a.b.c.d is my public ip). I can access the web page without any errors from inside the LAN when I type 192.168.1.2:80 (192.168.1.2 is the local ip address), but it leads me to the index page (showing the files and directories on the web server) when I type 192.168.1.2:8080. These three lines are included in ports.conf:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
Listen 8080
Listen 80
```

I'm not sure if I did it correctly because different links gave me different instructions, so here's how I'm forwarding the port in the router (it's an ADSL router, it's not connected to a modem or something):

```
Server Name: Apache2
External Port Start: 8080
External Port End: 8080
Protocol: TCP
Internal Port Start: 80
Internal Port End: 80
Server IP Address: 192.168.1.2
```

The server's local IP address (192.168.1.2) is static. I'm using http://www.canyouseeme.org/ to check for open ports. It returns a success with port 8080 and returns an error with port 80. When I enter a.b.c.d:80 in the URL bar, it leads me to the router's configuration page. Do I have to allow a port through firewall if I'm using Debian? Please tell me what is wrong or missing.

Comment: The firewall on your web server itself must be configured to allow the connection from external addresses - I assume it is set to deny anything which is not specifically allowed ("whitelisted"). When you say that you cannot access it from the external IP address, are you trying from a computer outside of your LAN (e.g. from a friend's house)? If you're trying to access it using the external IP address from within your LAN, the router would need to support loopback.

Comment: Why are you doing PAT on your router? PAT could lead to strange behaviour on web applications if you do not prepare them in advance. Since the Apache would be receiving connections on port `80` (router would connect to apache on that port), any auto-generated content could be using links with the same `80` port, but since port `80` is not open on your router, you would get that "This webpage is not available". Try doing a `telnet a.b.c.d 8080` and write `GET / HTTP/1.0` followed by two ENTERs. Check the response an look for URLs. I bet those have the wrong port (`80` or ommited).

Comment: @AndrewMorton I was actually trying to access it from inside the LAN. When I access it from outside the LAN it just keeps loading. Any idea what could the problem be now?

Comment: Is the port forwarding configured properly? Just in case my ISP is blocking port 80, is it possible to configure the port forwarding settings and ports.conf so that I can access the server from another port?